# How to uninstall Quebles from Windows Live Messenger?

Tags: uninstall, windows-live-messenger, plugins

I have installed [Quebles](http://www.quebles.com/) theme pack.

Now I'm trying to uninstall it from Messenger.

When Windows Live Messenger is open, there is a "Q" icon appearing on top left corner, and I don't know how to remove it.

When I Google it, it shows only site statistics and not ways to remove Quebles.

Comment: Here is a full installer for windows live essentials 2011 http://g.live.com/1rewlive4-all/en/wlsetup-all.exe. I can't find quebles references in registry neither in c:\ system files

Comment: I uninstalled messenger, and did a clean install, but quebles is still there. Perhaps it is registered somewhere in my profile or somehow in my Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is something that maybe will be useful.

First, click on your name, choose `Personalize` and then `Change your badge`:

[image]

Choose badges you want to remove, like Quebles for example:

[image]

Now the rest is easy, you can remove pictures and winkles without any trouble in Messenger.

It is horrible to see there is no uninstaller for this Quebles plugin, but you can tell Messenger 2011 to stop using it.

Comment: I found your answer quite informative, but my problem is that I still use Windows XP and I cannot find the way to get to 'Personalize' to delete Quebles from my badges...
I tried finding Quebles in my 'Add/Remove Programs', but was not in the list. After I deleted the application, which usually tells me if I want to delete the full thing from my pc, but it didn't. I cannot even find it in my Start menu... I'm lost! :S
is there a way to get it off please? regards...

Answer (score 1):

### How to uninstall Quebles:

1. Go to "Add or Remove Programs".
2. Look for the program called `SweetIM`.
   You should find SweetIM for Internet explorer's toolbar and another one
   for windows live messenger.
3. Right click on each of them and click uninstall.

If you have Firefox installed on your computer:

1. Go to your Firefox browser
2. Click on the menu and select "Add-ons"
3. Make sure you remove `SweetIM` if it is listed.